# Cannot boot win 8.1 without install cd

Tags: windows-8, uefi, secure-boot

I've formatted my HP laptop and installed a new win 8.1 from dvd. But now I cannot boot from hard drive unless the install CD is presented.

There's an error message displayed when booting in non legacy mode:
`boot device not found. Please install an operating system on your hard disk.`.

But when booting in legacy mode, I'm told that there's no bootable hard drive.

Please note that I've wiped the entire hard disk before installation.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve these boot device errors if they persist, perform the following steps in the order listed. If the computer still does not start, contact HP for assistance with this error.

1. Reset the BIOS default settings
2. Reseat the hard drive
3. Run HP Hard Disk Test
4. Respond to ‘Hard Disk Not Exist’ message
5. Recover the operating system

If the above steps does not work you can try the following
The hard drive may have been displaced slightly and is easy to check out. 
Remove the cover and reseat the hard drive. now try booting if still the problem persists,the hard drive may be damaged internally, but you will not find this out until you reseat it and try to install an OS onto it.

Before re-installing Windows, if possible that you can remove the drive, connect it up as a slave to another system and then run check disk(CHKDSK) on it. In some cases, this can correct issues with a drive which will not boot.

If check disk(CHKDSK) and a re-install don't work, you will have to replace the drive. You might want to have the entire machine checked out before spending cash on it..

Answer (score 0):

Error that is indicated above means that (any possible combination):

- You have not installed the OS properly (could be that additional HDD/USB drive was plugged in and during installation boot sector was created on that drive)
- You have changed boot sequence in BIOS to prioritize DVD drive but disabled HDD boot instead of lowering the priority of the boot for HDD by moving it lower on the boot sequence list
- SecureBoot is somehow fighting your PC configuration and you should try to disable it in BIOS